# Adding Razorviews/.chtml files non-dynamically in .NET 6.0

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I'm learning how to make a website and I want to add new views through a method. Instead of physically clicking add view and then editing it.

The method would take in a Novel object, which is connected to a database. If that novel doesn't already have a view. A new view would be created based off a template view that I make. Some areas in the template would be changed based off the difference in object properties. Ex. Novel Name, Synopsis, Author, Chapters, Rating, Genres, and Tags.

I already have a form that takes in information and makes an update to the sql database adding that object.

There are a lot of guides on how to do this dynamically, but later on I want to add reviews, comments, pageview trackers, and such.

Something similar to what I want.
[MVC 4: Create new Razor View from string not from file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644071/mvc-4-create-new-razor-view-from-string-not-from-file-path)

That method doesn't seem to work anymore or I'm just not that familiar with the syntax.

Comment: Are you using MVC 4 for asp.net core?

Comment: I'm using .NET 6.0, when making the project its ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller). I don't think its MVC 4.